# Поиск максимума на SQL Server которая принимает на вход два значения как в .Net?

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

Я хочу написать в своём запросе что-то типа:

```
SELECT o.OrderId, MAX(o.NegotiatedPrice, o.SuggestedPrice)
FROM Order o
```

Но ведь функция `MAX` так не работает, верно? Это же агрегатная функция, которая принимает один параметр и возвращает максимальное значение всех строк.

Может кто подскажет, как мне сделать подобное?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Is there a Max function in SQL Server that takes two values like Math.Max in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/124417/5752652) от участника  [@skb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14101/skb).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/124417/

Comment: Используйте `CASE WHEN a>b THEN a ELSE b END`. Вот для более чем двух аргументов так просто уже не выйдет...

Answer (score 1):

Для MS SQL Server 2008 или выше вы можете воспользоваться следующим вариантом:

```
SELECT o.OrderId,
       (SELECT MAX(Price)
        FROM (VALUES (o.NegotiatedPrice),(o.SuggestedPrice)) AS AllPrices(Price))
FROM Order o
```

Решение взято из ответа [Sven's answer to a related question, "SQL MAX of multiple columns?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871572/2865345)

и это самый лучший вариант ответа потому что:

1. Он не усложняет ваш код UNION's, PIVOT's,
   UNPIVOT's, UDF's и выражениями CASE сумашедшей длины.
2. Оно корректно обрабатывает null.
3. Он легко модифицируется, можно заменить "MAX" на "MIN", "AVG", или "SUM".   Вы можете использовать любые агрегатные функции над несколькими колонками.
4. Вы не ограничены в использовании имён (например, "AllPrices" и "Price"). Вы можете выбрать свои собственные имена для упрощения чтения и понимания.
5. Вы можете использовать несколько агрегатных функций используя [производные таблицы](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) например так:
    SELECT MAX(a), MAX(b) FROM (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10) ) AS MyTable(a, b)

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/9449247/5752652 от участника  [@MikeTeeVee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555798/miketeevee).</sub>

---

P.S. На en so есть [вариант ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/124474/5752652), который подходит и для более ранних версий MS SQL, а также [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/293804/5752652), основанный на математической формуле.